# What does a "runway hold position sign" denote?

Tags: airport-markings, faa-knowledge-test

I'm wondering why I got this question wrong, as I thought the point of hold positions were to protect aircraft from each other. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Take small comfort that your answer isn’t technically “wrong”, it just isn’t the best answer.

Comment: This is the evil of multiple guess questions.  They are diabolically structured with a correct and correctish-sounding answer and are based on the idea that parsing the difference is easy if you know the material really well, and if not, your answer is more of a guess with a 50/50 chance of failure.  Unfortunately, this requires a somewhat lawyerly skill at  linguistic interpretation.  Multiple guess exams must be hell for ESL types.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! The downfall of these multiple choice questions is that they sometimes have more than one answer... You'd think it would be easier with only three options.

Answer (score 13):

You are correct that the *general* idea of a "runway hold position" sign is to keep aircraft from hitting each other, but that applies to all three answers. You need to tighten your focus a little.

The [Aeronautical Information Manual paragraph 2–3–8](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html#%24paragraph2-3-8) is a reference you can use for this question. You can see that a **runway hold position sign** (2–3–8**b**1) denotes a holding position short of a runway *itself* while a **runway *approach area* holding position sign** (2–3–8**b**2) protects the approach (or departure) path to a runway even though the taxiway does not intersect with the actual runway pavement. Your selected answer "C" refers to a runway approach area holding position sign.

That said, I would call the question misleading because both answers "A" and "B" might refer to a runway holding position sign. But if you carefully parse the wording, answer "A" refers to intersecting runways *in general* while "B" refers specifically to the point where a taxiway *enters* a runway; a runway holding position sign encountered on another runway does not denote intersecting runways *in general* but—just like on a taxiway—the point where a runway *enters* another runway. It's a very fine point, but if I give the test-writer the benefit of the doubt I can see the difference.

...I'll still call it a misleading question though. But it's the sort of question you have to expect from the FAA.